# How can one tell whether one is referring to a class variable or an instance variable

Tags: python

Consider this little program

```
class Test:

    var1 = 0

    def test(self):
        print(f'Test.var1: {Test.var1}; self.var1: {self.var1}')
        self.var1 = 1
        print(f'Test.var1: {Test.var1}; self.var1: {self.var1}')

Test().test()
```

It produces this output

```
Test.var1: 0; self.var1: 0
Test.var1: 0; self.var1: 1
```

Apparently the first `self.var1` was taken to refer to `var1` the class variable, but the line

```
self.var1 = 1
```

was taken to mean that a new `var1` instance variable should be created. Then the third `self.var1` was taken to refer to that instance `var1`.

That means that `self.var1` has different meanings depending on whether an instance `var1` has been created. That strikes me as confusing. Wouldn't it be better to make the first `self.var1` what PyCharm calls an unresolved reference? What is the rationale for defining Python semantics this way?

Comment: It's really convenient when you call `Test().test()`, and the method only needs to exist in the class, not get copied to each instance.

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: “Rationale” questions are generally out of scope. After all, what is the “rationale” that Python isn’t statically typed?

Comment: With *class name*,  access instance variables and methods from file out of scope.  With *self*, access instance variables and methods inside class with out creating object of class.

Comment: See this: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks. To answer the rationale part, functions are first-class objects in python. So, returning the class attribute var1 when calling self.var1, is the equivalent of returning test when calling self.test. If it is required that class attributes are called via Test.var1 instead, doesn't it mean then that I/the dev need to keep track of which are class and which are instance attributes? It's usually a code smell when class and instance attributes are mixed up, so that just sounds like unnecessary complication to the language.